# C#: How to convert Task<T[]> to IEnumerable of Task<T>

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncCollection<MyItem[]>` which I want to wrap into something like `IAsyncEnumerable<MyItem>`.

For now I use just `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` instead of `IAsyncEnumerable`.

And I need something like `SelectMany` to flatten the list. And this is problem. The following code is not working.

Is it possible to get it work?

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> Flatten<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T[]>> source) {
    foreach (Task<T[]> task in source) {
        // We should convert Task<T[]> to IEnumerable of Task<T>
        T[] result = await task;
        foreach (T item in result) {
            yield return Task.FromResult( item );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe "not working"?

Comment: I use await in iterator method.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to wait a few months until `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is a real thing. The next-best solution is to use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` from [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/). But for now...

`IEnumerable<T>` is a synchronous pull iterator. So it has to provide its `T` instances synchronously. More to the point for this question, it has to provide its *count* of instances synchronously.

`Task<T>` is an asynchronous pull of a single item. It will only provide its `T` instance asynchronously.

So here's the problem: your desired result `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` must be able to:

1. Provide each `Task<T>` synchronously. Not too hard; you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` if absolutely necessary.
2. Provide its *count* synchronously. In other words, it needs to provide *every* `Task<T>` synchronously. All of them. This isn't possible, given your input.

Your input is `IEnumerable<Task<T[]>>`. Since this is `IEnumerable<>`, you can get the count synchronously, but this is only the count of the `Task<T[]>` items - i.e., the count of `T[]` items. To do a flatten operation, you would have to `await` each of those `Task<T[]>` items in order to get the count of `T` items. So you cannot produce an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` that can synchronously know how many items it has.

You're running into this type limitation because `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` is *not* the same as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

Your options are:

1. Use a real `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, written yourself or via System.Interactive.Async. Pros: proper types allow for semantically precise code. Cons: production and consumption of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is still a pain (for now).
2. Do all the asynchronous work up front. Pros: easier code. Cons: changes your desired semantics.

With the second option, your flatten operator could look like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Flatten<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T[]>> tasks) 
{
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  return results.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Until you have a true `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, many operators will require the future (`Task<T>`) to end up on the outside like this.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this
define Task and define your type in it and await the result , make sure what you are awaiting is async. like the method given below.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> getIEnumerable () {
 return await yourresult.toListAsync();

}
```